# Java data structure with multiple keys and not allows duplicate keys

Tags: java

I'm wondering if there are any Java data structures or libraries that would allow me to have multiple keys while not having duplicate keys?

In my use case I have two different types of keys: Personal Identification Number and Driver License. I want to use either keys to look up a value (their car in this example). When I try to add a duplicate key (pin-1), there should be an error as pin-1 is already assigned.

```
structure.add("pin-1", "driverLicense-1", Car.TOYOTA);
structure.add("pin-2", "driverLicense-2", Car.FORD);
structure.add("pin-1", "driverLicense-3", CAR.FORD); // invalid because pin-1 is already assigned
```

The only library I have encountered that does something like this is Google’s [Guava](https://guava.dev/) and its [`HashBasedTable`](https://guava.dev/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/HashBasedTable.html) class implementing [`Table`](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#table). The issue I have with this library is that it does not prevent duplicate keys.

```
Table<String, String, Car> table = HashBasedTable.create();
table.put("pin-1", "driverLicense-1", Car.TOYOTA);
table.put("pin-2", "driverLicense-2", Car.FORD);
table.put("pin-1", "driverLicense-3", Car.FORD); // is valid
```

Comment: map within a map? get("pin-1") returns a map. that map.get("driverLicense-3") returns a value?

Comment: Why do you claim that Guava `HashBasedTable` does not prevent duplicate keys? The Javadoc says the data is stored in a Map<R, Map<C, V>>. And a `Map` by definition cannot have duplicate keys.

Answer (score 4):

I would use two Maps, wrapped in a class which handles updating them together, e.g.:

```java
    class CarOwnership {
        private final Map<String,Car> byPin = new HashMap<>();
        private final Map<String,Car> byLicense = new HashMap<>();
        
        public void put(String pin, String licence, Car car) {
            if (byPin.containsKey(pin)) {
                throw new RuntimeException("duplicate pin " + pin);
            }
            if (byLicense.containsKey(licence)) {
                throw new RuntimeException("duplicate licence " + license);
            }
            byPin.put(pin, car);
            byLicense.put(licence, car);
        }
        
        public Car findByPin(String pin) {
            return byPin.get(pin);
        }
        ...
    }
```

The advantage of having a container around the actual data structure you're using is that it allows you to put your error handling in one place, and gives you somewhere to perform validation.

This is distinct from `HashBasedTable`, which is a Map of Maps, and so needs both components of the key to reach the value.

Comment: This is how the mentioned Guava [`HashBasedTable`](https://guava.dev/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/HashBasedTable.html) works, a map of maps: `Map<R, Map<C, V>>`. So it might make more sense to use Guava rather than write you own.

Comment: Doesn't `Table` require both keys to retrieve a value? My interpretation of the question is that you can retrieve  car with *either* a pin or a licence.

Comment: Yes, that seems to be the case with a `Table` & `HashBasidTable` in Guava, you must specify both keys ("row" & "column") to get a value. Using either key alone returns a `Map` rather than the desired value. So I stand corrected: You are using a pair of `Map` kept separate, whereas `HashBasedTable` is using a *nested* structure, with a `Map` leading to another `Map`. So your Answer does indeed provide a better solution for this Question. You might want to add a note on this distinction, since the Question specifically mentions Guava `HashBasedTable`.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, this can be achieved **by making an entry** in a map ***for each key passed***. So, there is **only one** map, but each call to `put()` potentially adds multiple entries (one entry for each key). Not sure if there is a built-in API in Java for this, but here is one simply implementation.

```
public class MultikeyMap<K, V>{
    /* Holds all the values. */
    private Map<K, V> map = new HashMap<>();
    
    /** Creates one entry in this.map for each key passed here. */
    public void put( V value, K... keys ) {
        if( keys == null || keys.length == 0 ) throw new NullPointerException();
        
        /* For every key, create an entry. */
        for( K key : keys ) map.putIfAbsent( key, value );
    }
    
    public V get( K key ) {
        if( key == null ) throw new NullPointerException();
        return map.get( key );
    }
    
    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return this.map.toString();
    }
    
    public static void main( String[] args ){
        MultikeyMap<String, Car> m = new MultikeyMap<>();
        
        m.put( Car.HONDA, "pin-1", "dl-1" );
        System.out.println( m );
        
        m.put( Car.TATA, "pin-2", "dl-2" );
        System.out.println( m );
        
        m.put( Car.TOYOTA, "pin-1", "dl-3" );
        System.out.println( m );
    }
    
    private static enum Car{
        TOYOTA, HONDA, MARUTI, TATA;
    }
}
```

Here's the output from running `main()`.

```
{pin-1=HONDA, dl-1=HONDA}
{pin-2=TATA, pin-1=HONDA, dl-2=TATA, dl-1=HONDA}
{pin-2=TATA, dl-3=TOYOTA, pin-1=HONDA, dl-2=TATA, dl-1=HONDA}
```

Some points about this design:

- When an existing key is encountered, it doesn't throw an exception; only ignores it.
- If we need various types in the key, then we may have to use `Map<Object, Car>`.